# How to make the background-image unresponsive in JS & CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my background-image's size to be at the size of the monitor's resolution (100%) and don't want it to be responsive like I don't want it to shrink while I shrink the browser's size, I want it to be scrollable when I shrink the browser's size. I'm kinda new at coding, any help would be greatly appreciated, here's what i've got, thanks.

```
.bg {
    background-image: url("pic.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: you need JS to get the screen size: `screen.width` and `screen.height` and then set the `background-size` attribute according to it through JS as inline-style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of javascript. Create CSS variables for the width and height and set them using `screen.width` and `screen.height` in javascript.

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg-width', `${screen.width}px`);
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bg-height', `${screen.height}px`);
```

```css
:root {
  --bg-width: 0;
  --bg-height: 0;
}

.bg {
  width: var(--bg-width);
  height: var(--bg-height);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630495325532-815f8d91a31e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3300&q=80" alt="" class="bg">
```

Keep in mind this approach won't preserve the aspect ratio of the image. One way to fix this problem is to only set the width or height of the image depending on which is bigger.